# Dimension of real inner product with unitary transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition, isometry

I want to prove the following statement:

> Given a unitary transformation $T$ on a real inner product space
>   $W$. $I$ is an identity matrix and $T$ has an orthonormal basis, then the
>   dimension of $W$ must be odd.

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of $T$? Their multiplicities?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Technically speaking, $T$ has no eigenvalues. The natural extension of $T$ to the complexification of $W$ will have some (non-real) eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $W$ has dimension $n$, then taking the determinant of both sides of $T^2=-I$ yields 
$$\det(T)^2=(-1)^n$$
which is impossible if $n$ is odd since $W$ is a real vector space.